# Consistent color for bindings in scheme-mode

Tags: font-lock, scheme

Take a look at the following example:

```scheme
(define a
  (lambda (x)
    (define b 1)
    (let ((y 2))
      #f)))
```

Emacs 28.2 renders the above code in this way:

[image: screenshot]

This is inconsistent. `define` introduces bindings for `a` and `b` and both are rendered blue. But `lambda` and `let` do also introduce a binding for `x` and `y`, but they are not blue.

How to fix this?

Comment: I guess the rationale might be that the 'define' creates global bindings (global within the scope it is created), while the lambda and the let create local bindings, i.e. bindings that are only valid within the body of its form (so that it presumably is less important to get 'alerted' about them). So I am not sure if this should be considered inconsistent behavior (although you might still prefer different behavior)...

Comment: `define` does not do anything "global". This fails: `(let () (let () (define a 1) a) a)`

Comment: I did not know how to word "global within the scope it got created" correctly. I guess maybe a better wording is that the variables bound via the lambda and the let are 'bound' variables, while the variables defined via define are 'free' variables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632495/6837095).